# How can a sequence of functions be dense in L^2

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Assume $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^d$ with sufficiently smooth boundary. Let $\{\lambda_n,\varphi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal eigensystem of the Laplacian opertor $-\Delta$, that is 
$$
-\Delta\varphi_n=\lambda_n\varphi_n,\quad \varphi_n\in H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega),\quad n=1,2,\dots
$$

Setting $c_n(x)=\int_0^T \psi(x,t)\exp(-\lambda_n(T-t))dt$, where $\psi\in C(\overline{\Omega}\times [0,T])$ and $\psi>0$ on $\overline \Omega\times[0,T]$,
I want to ask whether the span of $\{c_n\varphi_n\}$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$, that is
$$
\int_\Omega f(x)c_n(x)\varphi_n(x) dx=0,\quad \forall n=1,2,\dots
$$
implies $f\equiv0$ in $\Omega$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The condition you wrote just says that the span of $\{c_n \phi_n\}$ is dense.  You need more than that to have a (Schauder) basis.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the definition of the basis. Now I modified the question. Thank you.

Comment: The question is still not clear. You are starting with a basis and want conditions on the the sequence when multiplied with the basis which remain dense? Just take non-zero constants. If you start with an orthonormal system (not necessarily a basis) instead then there are functions whose products  will complete the system, google Boas-Pollard theorem for that.

Comment: I added my original problem. I hope it is clear enough.